# Tkinter Treeview how to change tree.item(Id)['text']

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Getting a Tkinter Treeview item's text is straight forward:

```py
my_text = tree.item(Id)['text']
```

I can't seem to find a way of setting the `text` to a new value.

I've tried:

```py
tree.set(Id, text=legal_string)
# TypeError: set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'

tree.set(Id, ['text']=legal_string)
# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

tree.set(Id)['text'] = legal_string
# Has no effect

tree.set(Id, "#0", legal_string)  # 'text'
# TclError: Display column #0 cannot be set

tree.set(Id, 0, legal_string)
# Changes Count/Last Access Column (first column, not 'text' or "#0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text or values by assigning the `text` or `values` option  of the `item` method. For further assistance and understanding maybe [this](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Treeview.html) will help.

```py
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk

db   = dict(Dad=("Bill",42),Mom=("Diane",39),Sister=("Stacey",18),Self=("Macie",18))
cols = ("Name", "Age")


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        
        tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=cols)
        
        tree.heading('#0', text='Relative')
        for col in cols: 
            tree.heading(col, text=col)
        
        iids = [tree.insert('', i, text=k, values=v) for i,(k,v) in enumerate(db.items())] 
        
        #Macie - this is Dad. Your sister is not evil, but she is our favorite. Fix this.
        tree.item(iids[2], text="Evil Twin", values=("TwoFacey", 18))
        
        tree.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Root().mainloop()
```